# Cutting the earbuds and keep the microphone: will it work?

Tags: circuit-design, microphone, headphones, condenser-microphone

I have old still functioning earphones with a microphone incorporated. 

I want to keep the microphone and remove the earbud so that I can then put the microphone inside a small pipe and record sounds.

 I wonder if just cutting the wires powering the earbud will do the job (see picture below, scissors to indicate where I intend to cut). I am worried that this way the microphone will not work (i.e.light brown wire seems connected to black microphone wire through the mystery button).

(I am not an expert in electrical engineer at all, so sorry if my question seems too trivial to you)
[image]

Comment: The problem is not that the question is trivial, but that the design of the product is unknown, so no amount of technical knowledge is going to help answer the question, unless someone already knows the design and happens to recognize the product in the photo. I suggest you try it. Best case, it just works. Worst case, you lose an old set of earphones. Judging by the wiring it might work, but don't hold me accountable if it doesn't.

Comment: I was hoping that the design of microphones in typical earphones is very similar between models so that the wiring design is the same. Anyway if that is not the case, the only option is to try.

Comment: Just buy a microphone.

Comment: I have tried to cut it and it worked

Comment: it is similar in most... Android mandates a certain wiring pattern so they're all pretty-much the same. @Dampmaskin it's hard to immagine a sensible setup where cutting the branch that feeds the ears  would impact the performance of the microphone.